# Parse data from multiple Json objects

Tags: php, android, json

```
{"num":"111111111111","result":"yes"}
{"num":"9724321456","result":"yes"}
{"num":"5555555555","result":"no"}
{"num":"1111111112","result":"yes"}
{"num":"7878889978","result":"yes"}
```

I get data in this format from server it is not enclosed into a json array as no"[" brackets.
I am really struggling to retrieve this values.
I have tried several approaches like getting

job.keys();

job.names();

But none seen to work.

I can also request server to change PHP code but not if its possible via Android.

PHP CODE:

```
  if($bool){
$array['num']=$checknum2;
$array['result']="yes";

}else{
$array['num']=$checknum2;
$array['result']="no";



print(json_encode($array));
```

This is in a loop

Comment: yes but it only gives the first object

Comment: change on the server side make it array of json objects

Comment: That is because the json you have posted is `invalid`.

Comment: Its in PHP if($bool){
    $array['num']=$checknum2;
    $array['result']="yes";
     
    }else{
    $array['num']=$checknum2;
   $array['result']="no";
   
    
  
     print(json_encode($array));

Comment: Json data can be json object it does not strictly have to be an array

Comment: @user2800040 for you case it would be better if you have `[
    {
        "num": "111111111111",
        "result": "yes"
    },
    {
        "num": "9724321456",
        "result": "yes"
    },
    {
        "num": "5555555555",
        "result": "no"
    },
    {
        "num": "1111111112",
        "result": "yes"
    },
    {
        "num": "7878889978",
        "result": "yes"
    }
]`

Comment: Also if i can make change in php code thats also fine

Comment: ues @Raghunandan but i dont know how to get such output via php.I have pasted the code if you can help me

Comment: Fact: You can't do anything if you don't have a size(limit)..You must have to put all jsonObjects inside one JsonArray which is the server part of your program..

Comment: @user2800040 well i don't work on php. why don't you tag php also so that you will get better answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it via PHP

I used

While in the loop keep pushing small array to big

```
array_push($arraybig,$array);
```

At the end

```
print(json_encode($arraybig));
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code, where result is your response string from server.

```
        JSONObject json = null;
        result = String.format("[" + result + "]"); 

        JSONArray jArray;
        try {

            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

            String num = json.getString("num");
            String result = json.getString("result");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

PHP service code must be something like this:

```
 $resultArray = array();

 // LOOP body start

 if($bool){
 $array['num']=$checknum2;
 $array['result']="yes";

 }else{
 $array['num']=$checknum2;
 $array['result']="no";
 }

 $resultArray[$count] = $array;
 $count++;

 // LOOP body end

 json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: I get error 08-21 17:36:09.316: W/chatcheck(6219): caught at chatcheck:-org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 36 {"num":"9574228386","result":"no"}{"num":"8460164824","result":"no"}{"num":"9624447291","result":"no"}{"num":"918866469527","result":"no"}

Comment: you can check now, have to edit your service code as well. cheers :)